# How to cache images with different names using cloudinary in Codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone, cloudinary

If I use codenameone URLImage, I can specify a filename for cached images... for example, I can have **MyPic_Big.jpg** and **MyPic_Small.jpg** as images coming from the same URL and possibly with different sizes.

Is there a way to do the same using cloudinary in codenameone or the Java API?

My use case is that I want to fetch 2 different sizes of the same image using transformation. What I noticed is that if the bigger version has already been fetched, the smaller version will use that because it found the filename in storage and Vice-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you have answered this question yourself, by adding the functionality.  I have merged your support for cacheName() to allow you to explicitly set the cache name.  For future reference, the example usage is here:

https://github.com/shannah/cloudinary-codenameone/blob/3ce84fedd2f8364f64885de9390fe0da4d2c2725/src/com/codename1/cloudinary/CloudinaryDemo.java#L74-L79

Download the latest release here:
https://github.com/shannah/cloudinary-codenameone/releases/latest

Answer (score 1):

Codename has only recently introduced an integration to Cloudinary :)

More information is available on their blog-post:
https://www.codenameone.com/blog/sizing-images-just-right-with-cloudinary.html

Here's a link to their git repo:
https://github.com/shannah/cloudinary-codenameone

Furthermore, Cloudinary also provides an official and comprehensive JAVA integration.
For more information, including setup instruction and code examples, see:
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/java_integration

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm aware of all these. My question is how to specify filename when caching images in codenameone and/or java